# Syncing Error on monerod

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

I've been struggling with syncing my wallet. I'm a first time user, but the struggle has been going on for 5 days.

I transfered XMR to my walltet, but it's still not showing up. I've tried syncing locally as well as from a remote node.

But, I keep getting "failed to connect to any seed peers; continuing with out seeds" error.

My network status reflects as connected and i've opened up port 18081 on my firewall.

What am I doing wrong? I'd really appreciate some step by step instructions. I'm not super technical, but given instruction I can execute.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using GUI or CLI? What happened when you tried to sync with remote node? port 18081 is default for wallet sync (wallet talking to a node). If you want to run a full node, you need to open 18080 (node talking to another node).

Comment: I am using GUI. I synced to node.moneroworld.com port number 18089. I also tried syncing to localhost port 18081, but in both cases I get the "failed to connect to any seed peers". I opened up monerod and did the print_cn.  There are connections showing up, but all have 0 for Peer ID and 0 for and Down and Up.

Comment: Could you verify whether your transaction actually arrived? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived

Comment: I've confirmed that it arrived. It's been several days, I've been trying to troubleshoot this, but i'm not getting anywhere. I show as being connected, but I don't think i'm syncing as I keep getting the "failed to connect" error.

Comment: Ok, let's try to connect to a remote node again: https://moneroworld.com/#nodes. Does it state `Connected` if you connect to a remote node? If so, try these steps. [1] Exit the GUI. [2] Remove the wallet cache: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/how-do-i-delete-the-wallet-cache/3123. [3] Restart the GUI.