# Funds not reflecting in GUI

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui, synchronization, balance

So I was having some problems syncing my GUI to the blockchain, and as a result I wasn't able to view my balance. But i've since been able to correct the syncing problem by downloading to the latest version of the GUI V0.11.0.0

It took about 3 days, but I was able to fully sync, but the problem is my balance isn't showing up. I've confirmed that the transaction went through, and the folks at ShapShift confirmed as well. I also confirmed the wallet address was correct. What am I doing wrong.

This is the current status I'm showing- Height: 1428735/1428735 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 269.15 MH/s, v6, up to date, 9(out)+3(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 22m 34s

Comment: Try these steps -> 1. Exit the GUI. 2. Remove the wallet cache: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/how-do-i-delete-the-wallet-cache/3123 3. Restart the GUI.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE Thanks so much! That worked. It's great to have the community here to help. But, why does it have to be so difficult to use Monero... :(   Anyway, I know I can count on the help of others here. Thanks again.