# What is the other file created alongside .keys?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I created a wallet called ”Test”.

Two files were created (`Test` and `Test.keys`).

According to https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3123/11776, `Test` is the wallet cache.

What is the purpose of this cache and does it change significantly over time (does its size remain relatively constant over time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache contains data that's retrieved from the blockchain. It includes the hashes of blocks (used to detect reorgs), then data for every transaction that you sent or received, custom information like user tx notes, secret transaction keys, that kind of thing. It will grow as you transact in Monero.

Comment: Thanks so much for shedding light on this... would you happen to know how much space one needs to allocate to this data on limited hardware (we're talking a few MBs, a few dozen MBs or in the hundreds of MBs)?

Comment: A few dozen ought to do. Less if your wallet is seldom used.